# WEB-INF web.xml - How to configure to serve local file resources

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

How do I configure a servlet to serve certain URLs from local files? Eg for CSS, images, JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the under WEB-INF and refer to them by path relative to that.  No special configuration needed.

In your WAR:

```
WEB-INF
 +
 | 
 +----css
 +----js
 +----images
```

In your page:

```
<script src="js/foo.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Just curious, is the content of WEB-INF folder cannot be accessed as web-resources?

Answer (score 0):

**With Servlet 3.0**, you can put your static content in JAR with below structure and place this jar inside WEB-INF/lib.

```
WEB_INF
   |
   +--lib/META-INF/resources/test.css
```

META-INF/resources will be mapped to the docroot of your web application.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to put these folder in **webapp** folder just beside WEB-INF folder or put it in

```
WEB_INF
|
+--lib/META-INF/resources/
```

folder as stated by ALOK